# Java Security Exception list does not work

Tags: java, list, security, exception, applet

I have a problem with adding sites to the java security exception list.
According to the documentation (http://java.com/en/download/faq/exception_sitelist.xml) the exception list does exactly what I want.
Stop this stupid security message and let me use the application which I KNOW is secure.

Following setup:
Ubuntu Development machine, running application server with a little java applet on the login page (Do not ask why, I don't know thats how the application works).
If I use my local browser everything works fine.

But I have to test the site with Windows in an virtual box VM.
I have an IE8/Win7 image from modern.ie running.

I installed the latest java on this VM and every time I try to login the Java applet is blocked because of my security settings (yeah.. "my").

I added the hostname of my machine to the exception list in the java control panel (in the vm of course).
But this does not change anything it.

The application runs at http://myhost:1234/APPLICATION-NAME
I've added every possible combination to the exception list like:
http://myhost
http://myhost:1234 (with and without trailing /)
http://myhost:1234/APPLICATION-Name (with and without trailing /).

nothing worked.

Does anyone know if this exception list thing still works as stated on the FAQ page from oracle?
Why is there not a button named "oracle I know what I'm doing".